# Entity Framework Core 6.0 Throws Sequence Does Not Contain Elements

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm using Entity Framework Core 6.0.3 in a .Net 6.0 application.

I wrote an extension method off my DB Context to allow me to run stored procedures.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> SqlQueryAsync<TResult>(this DbContext db, string sql, DbConnectionInterceptor interceptor = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, params object[] parameters) where TResult : class
{
    await using var context = new ContextForQuery<TResult>(db.Database.GetDbConnection(), db.Database.CurrentTransaction, interceptor);

    return await context.Set<TResult>().FromSqlRaw(sql, parameters).ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

The statement `ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken)` is causing an error when `FromSqlRaw` has no results. If I change to `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, I get no error, but I need all results. It also fails on `AnyAsync()` and `ToListAsync()` with the same error. Everything appears to work when data is returned.

The stack trace shows an error in the underlying code where EF is calling `.Max` on an empty collection.

> System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements
>
> at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Max(IEnumerable`1 source)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)

Am I misusing something or is there a way I can catch an empty result set before converting to an array?

Comment: Show entity model or check that model is not read-only.

Comment: It's a stored procedure.  It does not necessarily return an entity model.  In the case of my tests, I have tried a simple DTO with public properties (failed) and a dynamic (also failed).  The error is the same.  EF is running a .Max on an empty collection and throwing an error.

Comment: Show DTO with public properties that you have tried.

Comment: Actually I'm interested in Does properties of this DTO are writable or not.